# Not able to see data when returning from firebase in angular4

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to receive some data in my component using firebase.

```
brandsList: AngularFireList<any> = null;

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _af: AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.brandsList = this._af.list('/all-brands');
    console.log(this.brandsList);
  }
```

in console it logs, but no data.

{query: Reference, update: ƒ, set: ƒ, push: ƒ, remove: ƒ, …}
auditTrail
:
ƒ (events)
push
:
ƒ (data)
query
:
Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
remove
:
ƒ remove(item)
set
:
ƒ dataOperation(item, value)
snapshotChanges
:
ƒ (events)
stateChanges
:
ƒ (events)
update
:
ƒ dataOperation(item, value)
valueChanges
:
ƒ (events)
**proto**
:
Object

How to get data and iterate over it. 
I verified the firebase path in browser and it gives data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
this.brandsList = this._af.list('/all-brands').valueChanges();;
```

Comment: with that i am seeing this error. Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>'.

Comment: which means you are getting the response, just change the type

Comment: yeah. Got it now. Thanks.